# Convex solver returns disordered dual variables, how to re-order?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I have the following convex optimization problem:

$$
\begin{align*}
\min_{x} &f(x) \\
\text{subject to} \\
x_{k+1} &= x_k+\cdots\qquad k=0,1,2,\ldots,N-1
\end{align*}
$$

I managed to solve the above problem using YALMIP, using its very fast `optimizer` parser. Unfortunately, while `optimizer` can give me the dual variables associated with my $N$ constraints, it gives them out of order - in other words, the second element in the array of duals that `optimizer` returns does not necessarily correspond to the dual of the constraint $x_2=x_1+\cdots$.

Question: how can I recover the duals of this optimization problem, either by direct calculation or by matching the out-of-order duals that I have with the constraints?

I think this is a mathematical question rather than a programming one. In the end, I'm just asking how I can compute the duals of an already-solved optimization problem.

Comment: You're better off asking that question on the YALMIP forum as this is very YALMIP specific. I don't see why the order would be changed for this problem, so please post an MVE on the YALMIP forum and I'll try to answer it there.

Comment: It's not straightforward, see comments and answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279435/how-to-compute-primal-variable-based-on-dual-variables-and-their-multipliers